# How can I delete openvpn from Red Hat 8?

Tags: vpn, uninstall, redhat-enterprise-linux, undo, openvpn

https://openvpn.net/vpn-software-packages/redhat/ I ran through this setup, but don't know how to undo it. 
Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following command to remove the package.

```sh
yum remove openvpn-as
```

Comment: Thanks! What does the -as mean?